# Maintain user session with Route 53

Tags: session, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns

**Problem description:**

I have 2 EC2 instances which are located in the Europe and North America region. Now I have setup a Route 53 to direct user request to these servers with [Weighted Round Robin record set](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/WeightedResourceRecordSets.html)

When user being directed to one server and created session, the next time it resolve the domain name it could be direct to the other server which doesn't have the session. (e.g user logged in and clicked another link and has to login again)

**Thoughts:**

I could have a load balancer to ensure session stickiness of both server but in this case the Weighted Round Robin DNS routing can't be set.

I can also increase the TTL of DNS response but again it almost eliminates the effect of WRR.

Or I could configure servers to share sessions (which I don't know how to. The server is [Ofbiz server](http://ofbiz.apache.org/)) and I am not sure whether it is good practice.

**Question:**

Is there a way to maintain user sessions while using Weighted Round Robin Record on Amazon Web Service Route 53 ?

Many thanks !

Answer (score 0):

DNS round-robin works perfect for a short-life TCP connection (e.g. Performing a query). However, If you want to provide a longer session, please make sure that you have a longer-life session between your client and server. You can use [HTTPSession](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html) between your servers and clients and the Connection will stay open till the session gets expired.

As you mentioned, increasing TTL will not solve the problem because you could set a TCP connection close to expiry time of one DNS response and next time you get different IP address from a new DNS response.

If you don't want to use HTTPSession for any reason, you probably better use [Elastic Load Balancing (ELB)](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/) to do the same thing for you.

Comment: Hi Mjan thanks for your help! I think if the TCP connection can stay open until the session expired the problem will be solved, but how/is it possible to set TCP connection expiry time ? I simplified the scenario. Actually I have 2 group of EC2 and each has 2 instances and the 2 group located in those 2 region. There is actually a ELB in front of each group to maintain session. But I want to find a best Route53 "Weight" for each side such that the cost and performance are relatively optimal.

Comment: And the Ofbiz site actually has session. The difference between using and not using HTTPSession is that when user visiting different pages of a website on one server its session is maintained but when it being directed to another server no matter how long the session is, it will be lost. This will happen when user simply reload the web page.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to define session for TCP connection. However, it can be implemented via HTTP (which sits on top of TCP).

Comment: One  more approach is to store the sessions in a NoSql database (web application programmers use REDIS for this purpose). It is very effective and reliable.

Comment: Ok. I thought about storing session info in database, but the servers that given to me are Apache Ofbiz servers. Don't know how to configure it to store session in database. Thanks for your reply anyway !